# php manipulation of one data simple basic php code execution

Tags: php

I have to solve an assignment question that touches on the simple basic php codings learnt in class so far..the question goes:

Arithmetic-assignment operators perform an arithmetic operation on the variable at the same time as assigning a new value. Write a script to reproduce the output below. Manipulate only one variable using no simple arithmetic operators to produce the values given in the statements.

Hint: In the script each statement ends with "Value is now $variable."

```
Output:

Value is now 8.
Add 2. Value is now 10.
Subtract 4. Value is now 6.
Multiply by 5. Value is now 30.
Divide by 3. Value is now 10.
Increment value by one. Value is now 11.
Decrement value by one. Value is now 10.
```

Do you guys think the question is telling me to use arrays??

Coz I'm just gonna take a swing at this and assume it is arrays that this question wants me to write.. Then here is my sample answer. Hope you guys could check it out and see if my answer meets the question's needs:

```
    <?php
    $numbers=array("8","10","6","30","11");
    echo "Value is now {$numbers[0]}.<br>";
    echo "Add 2. Value is now {$numbers[1]}.<br>";
    echo "Subtract 4. Value is now {$numbers[2]}.<br>";
    echo "Multiply by 5. Value is now{$numbers[3]}.<br>";
    echo "Divide by 3. Value is now {$numbers[1]}.<br>";
    echo "Increment value by one. Value is now {$numbers[4]}.<br>";
    echo "Decrement value by one. Value is now {$numbers[1]}.<br>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Of course , you did a great job. Additional : you can use \n to run a new line too. <br> is for html , and if your assignment is about only PHP. Using \n would be more suitable.

Comment: am i understanding your question right? your assignment is about arithmetic? where are your operations on your answer? (multiply, divide, subtract, add)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are asked to use the [arithmetic operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

If so it should be like:

```
<?php
    $value = 8;
    echo "Value is now $value.<br>";
    echo "Add 2. Value is now " . $value+=2 . ".<br>";
    echo "Subtract 4. Value is now " . $value-=4 . ".<br>";
    echo "Multiply by 5. Value is now" . $value*=5 . ".<br>";
    // do the rest as this is an assignment
?>
```

You can play with it [here](https://eval.in/140070).

Note:

> `<br>` is for HTML. If you are only asked to use PHP then use `\r\n`.